# Accessing macOS Recovery Mode without Internet access?

Tags: macos, recovery

When starting my MacBook in recovery mode with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>, it prompts me to `Choose Network...`. The process that takes place immediately after entering my Wi-Fi password can take several minutes and it's kinda frustrating.

Is it possible to access recovery mode without connecting to the Internet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Recovery Partition on the system disk corresponds to the version of the macOS installed and should be loaded when holding <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> at boot (not <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>). However, if there is no recovery partition on the disk it will automatically revert to **Internet Recovery** which means downloading the boot image from Apple servers. Mac will also do that if there is a version mismatch from Recovery and macOS version installed. Remember that you should be able to use <kbd>option</kbd> key at boot which invokes **Startup Manager** which lets you select the available boot volumes, including the Recovery partition (without downloading from the Internet).

Nonetheless, according to [HT204904](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204904) there are actually several key combinations for Recovery:

<kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - Install the latest macOS that was installed on your Mac, without upgrading to a later version.

<kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - Upgrade to the latest macOS that is compatible with your Mac

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> - Install the macOS that came with your Mac, or the version closest to it that is still available.